# Bootstrap inline "width" style for label

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, width, inline

I try to adjust the width of an Bootstrap label with inline style.

This is my code:

```
<td><span class="label label-info" style="width:30px; text-align:center; background-color:#6d8cbf">  TEXT  </span></td>
```

Unfortunately, my label does not have the size of 30px. It always auto adjists himself to the minimal required size based on the text length.

Hope someone could help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since span is an inline-element it has no width and height.

What you could do is simply adding `display: block` to the inline style.

```
<td>
  <span style="display: block; width: 30px;">TEXT</span>
</td>
```

To give the text more space you could also use `padding`. For example

```
<td>
  <span style="padding: 10px 20px;">TEXT</span>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
But it does not work. http://www.bootply.com/AtikxSvhQT

Comment: Thank you. Works basically. But the Text is not anymore well centered.... But it works. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. With _not well centered_ do you mean horizontally or vertically? Because as I looked at the result the text seemed to be fine centered.